# How to Migrate 4TB Json data to Hadoop?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I Have PCM(Product Catalog) data of 4TB json which our devops will take dump from mongoDB every day .As part of building Data Warehouse we want to move it HDFS and expose this data as hive table for analytics.I don't get mongoDB access.I can only ask them to give dump in any file format.Currently I am created staging table using JSONSerde to read HDFS where this json file is moved and created final table of ORC format so that my hive queries will be faster.Can any one suggest best way to read large data(4TB) json in Hadoop.Our cluster can't afford Spark.I tried parsing each filed by get_json_object method it still takes more time and resources than Hive JsonSerde.

Note: please don't spam if you knows better way then only reply

Comment: This is simply too broad for a question and is more related to data management/warehousing than programming

Comment: Yes @ Andreas  I want to use Hive to solve this is not programming question

Comment: Why not just use Hive to read directly from Mongo? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage#connecting-to-mongodb---mongostoragehandler Otherwise, dumping the database to HDFS is really the only solution here...